# Просто способ хранения данных

Tags: python, база-данных

Скажите, пожалуйста, как поступить? Есть некая система, которая получает на вход ID. Например 5555. Она должна заглядывать в хранилище данных и проверять наличие этого ID (5555) в существующей базе. Если нет, то добавить, если есть, то ничего не делать. К сожалению, я не знаком с SQL и это всего лишь эксперимент социальный. Как еще можно хранить данные? Возможно ли какое-то решение, которое идеально подойдет для простоты и лаконичности кода. Прошу прощения, если вопрос очень обобщен. Надеюсь описанной схемы будет достаточно.

Comment: Да можете и просто в файле все `id` хранить, если система будет однопоточная. Вот если возможен многопоточный доступ, тогда будут проблемы и проще всё-таки в БД с транзакциями хранить.

Comment: Данные можно хранить как угодно. Нужно больше информации. Насколько важна сохранность данных? Как долго они будут актуальны? Какие будут взаимосвязи? И ещё много вопросов. Если нужно хранить только ID, то я бы вообще на SQL не смотрел, а взял бы [Redis](https://redis.io/)